# Warning: System.Web.dll built without parts that depend on: System.Web.Services.dll Mono.Web.dll

Tags: c++, mono

I am building mono (2.6.3) on Ubuntu 9.10

I am getting the following error:

Warning: System.Web.dll built without parts that depend on: System.Web.Services.dll Mono.Web.dll

Does anyone know what is causing this, and how I may resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Web.dll contains a cyclic dependency on System.Web.Services.dll.

So what happens is Mono builds a version of System.Web that does not depend on S.W.S, then uses that to build S.W.S, and finally builds the final System.Web which replaces the first one.

This probably should not use the word warning.  It is just the way things are, and it cannot be resolved.

Comment: @jpobst: Thanks for the clarification. Incidentally, do you have any links you could point me to regarding this?

Comment: I don't really know what kind of links you want.  Here's the patch that added it: http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-patches@lists.ximian.com/msg10687.html